# Segmentaion fault in C when doing matrix multiplication

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, matrix-multiplication, gsl

I use gsl random generator to generate 2 big matrices, and use gsl cblas to multiply them, but I always got Segmentation fault when the cblas operation begins. When I can't solve this, I then write the code below, using the very basic idea to do matrix multiplication, and I still got Segmentation Fault, but all the two can work all right when matrix is really a small one, I'm really puzzled about this.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#define PI 3.1415926

void GenerateKey(int m, int n, int l, int q, float alpha)
{
    // initialization
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;

    float *A;
    float *S;
    float *E;
    float *B;

    float sigma = (alpha * q ) / sqrt(2 * PI);
    A=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*(m*n));
    S=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*(n*l));
    B=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*(m*l));
    E=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*(m*l));

    // init A
    for(i = 0; i < m*n; i++)
    {
        A[i]=0;
    }
    printf("\n");

    // init S
    for(i = 0; i < n*l; i++)
    {
        S[i]=0;
    }

    printf("\n");

    // init E
    for(i = 0; i < m*l; i++)
    {
        E[i]=0;
    }

    printf("\n");
    float po;
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<l; j++)
        {      
            po=0;
            for(k=0; k<n; k++)
            {
                po +=A[i*m+k]*S[k*n+j];
            }
            po += E[i*m +j];
            B[i*m+j]=((int)po) % q;
        }
    }

    printf("Game over");

    printf("\n");
    free(A);
    free(B);
    free(S);
    free(E);
}

int main()
{
    GenerateKey(2680,191,64,72973,0.000551);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you treating these *matrices* as one-dimensional arrays?

Comment: `gdb` says that the error is at the row number 78, for a seg fault just use `valgrind` or `gdb`.

Comment: In fact, I want to implement matrix multiplication using gsl cblas functions, and this function requires one-dimentional arrays, because this function also gives me  segemation fault, so I write this program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're doing `i*m+j`, shouldn't that be `i*l+j` ? Similarly with `i*m+k` should be `i*l+k` and `k*n+j` should be `k*l+j`

The reason being, take for example `E = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*(m*l))`, so you have `m` rows and `l` columns (or vise versa), so if you are iterating over the `m` dimension you need to be multiplying your `m` iterator (`i` in this case) by the stride of your matrix in that dimension, which is `l`.

Comment: Just to add: An easy way to check is to replace the loop counter with the maximum value it can take in the array index. It is easy to see immediately that i * m + k --> m * m + n is weird, since A is m * n size only.

Comment: Thanks, I really made a misatake in indexing. when using array, I always make same kind of mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You don't check the `malloc()` return values, so my guess is that one or more allocation is failing and you're dereferencing `NULL`. Another possibility is of course an indexing error, so you acccess out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You incorrectly compute an element index for all the matrices.

When you have an `MxN` matrix which is allocated as an 1-dimensional array, the index for an element `(i,j)` is `i*N+j`. Instead, you're computing it as `i*M+j`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really made a misatake in indexing.